# create a loop that fills a vector with the number of "NA" values by column

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a loop that fills a vector "naVals" with the number of "NA" values by column in a data frame "wb." so far I have this:

```
naVals <- rep(NA, 24)
for (i in 1:24){
    naVals[i] <- sum(is.na(wb$v[i]))
}
```

this is not working and i can't figure out why!

```
naVals <- apply(wb,2,function(wb)sum(is.na(wb)))
```

(I know that this code does the same thing, but I'd like to do it as a loop if possible. Thanks so much!

Comment: If `wb` is a data frame, I would probably opt for something like `sapply(wb,function(x) sum(is.na(x)))`.

Comment: ...your `for` loop would probably work if you change `wb$v[i]` to `wb[[i]]`.

Comment: What is `v` anyway? Another variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @joran in the comments, your for loop would work if you replace `wb$v[i]` with `wb[[i]]`.

In the form that you have currently posted, you have already extracted column `v` and are subsetting on rows rather than columns. What you want is:

```
naVals <- rep(NA, 24)
for (i in 1:24) {
    naVals[i] <- sum(is.na(wb[[i]]))
}
```

Some extra advice, though. If you want this code to be adaptable to different data frames and not so specific then I recommend the following:

```
naVals <- numeric()
for (i in ncol(wb)) {
    naVals[i] <- sum(is.na(wb[[i]]))
}
```

This way you don't have to constantly edit both the for loop and the `naVals` initialization. You only need to use it on a new `wb`.

Comment: Maybe `numeric(24)` is better.

Comment: Would it make much of a difference? Regardless of initializing it empty or with some idle spaces, you could still append to it?

Comment: The difference is that it allocates memory beforehand. This is usually better than to keep extending the vector (append operations). With a length of just 24 it is probably irrelevant, but I find it a good habit. Anyway I upvoted.